# Send information to intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I first practiced this code in its own activity. But now i want to send the time text information to another activity using intent, but i just cant find out how, you see i need to have a **string** to send that information to another activity using an intent method, but my time text is just a **TextView** and not a string. And when i tried changing it to a string the **.setText** method did not work with it. What do you think i should do?

code:

```
handsomeButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                        int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                        new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                long millis = millisUntilFinished;

                                //set text

                                String hms = String.format("Viberation end in: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                                myText.setText(hms);



                            public void onFinish() {

                                myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                            }
                        }.start();
```

Basically I want to show ***myText*** in a new activity.

Comment: Just use myText.getText()

Comment: use myText.getText().toString()

Comment: you want to send a TextView object over intent? don´t do this, create a textview in the receiver activity and set only the text....

Comment: Okay now I'm confused and getting down votes..

Answer (score 0):

**1)How to send and get integer from extra?**

Sender Side:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("VariableName", str);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Receiver Side:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
String strValue = mIntent.getStringExtra("VariableName");
```

**2)** **How to capture text from text field into string?**

```
//TFusername is a TextView 
TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);

//Now get text inside this TextView
String str = a.getText().toString();
```

Comment: im getting an error in the ("VariableName", 0) parameter with the 0 says it should be a string

Comment: I updated the answer. Please remove this part  `,0`. It is not used for string. It is used for integer

Comment: @Kardio Please let me know if you are still having an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get text value from your myText - myText.getText().toString(); - and then put it as extra string of the intent of your new activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("myTextValue",myText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

and in your target activity onCreate method :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("myTextValue","default value");
```

Comment: can you explain what "myTextValue" and "default value" are please?

Comment: myTextValue is the tag of the value , and default value is a value used when myTextValue is null , exemple , lets suppose your put "value one" in myTextValue as extra , as soon as you call getIntent().getStringExtra("myTextValue","default value"); you will retrieve "value one" . if you do not put anything in myTextValue , when you will call getIntent().getStringExtra("myTextValue","default value") , you will retrieve "default value" .